Scan to PC buttons on canon mf232
Are there any solution to the scan to PC buttons found on my canon mf232 combined scanner printer?
I am able to scan documents from the scan document app but it when pressing the button on the machine it complains about it couldn't find the PC.
Any workarounds?
Update: Download the linux drivers from canon did not help, and neither did the documentation from the user manual do, it only describes the flow which works for windows

not really a Ubuntu issue but this Canon user manual resource should help

Sorry maybe I need to clarify the question, above link works fine for windows but not linux

@graham This is a problem in Ubuntu for me, but maybe it is not implemented
